# byte reverse AB CD to CD AB with python

Tags: python, byte, reversing

I have a .bin file, and I want to simply byte reverse the hex data. Say for instance @ 0x10 it reads AD DE DE C0, want it to read DE AD C0 DE.

I know there is a simple way to do this, but I am am beginner and just learning python and am trying to make a few simple programs to help me through my daily tasks. I would like to convert the whole file this way, not just 0x10.

I will be converting at start offset 0x000000 and blocksize/length is 1000000.

here is my code, maybe you can tell me what to do. i am sure i am just not getting it, and i am new to programming and python. if you could help me i would very much appreciate it.

```
def main():
    infile = open("file.bin", "rb")
    new_pos = int("0x000000", 16)
    chunk = int("1000000", 16)
    data = infile.read(chunk)
    reverse(data)

def reverse(data):
    output(data)

def output(data):
    with open("reversed", "wb") as outfile:
        outfile.write(data)

main()
```

and you can see the module for reversing, i have tried many different suggestions and it will either pass the file through untouched, or it will throw errors. i know module reverse is empty now, but i have tried all kinds of things. i just need module reverse to convert AB CD to CD AB.
thanks for any input

EDIT: the file is 16 MB and i want to reverse the byte order of the whole file.

Comment: You... never actually reverse anything...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Python 2, the binary file gets read as a string, so string slicing should easily handle the swapping of adjacent bytes:

```
>>> original = '\xAD\xDE\xDE\xC0'
>>> ''.join([c for t in zip(original[1::2], original[::2]) for c in t])
'\xde\xad\xc0\xde'
```

In Python 3, the binary file gets read as bytes.  Only a small modification is need to build another array of bytes:

```
>>> original = b'\xAD\xDE\xDE\xC0'
>>> bytes([c for t in zip(original[1::2], original[::2]) for c in t])
b'\xde\xad\xc0\xde'
```

You could also use the `<` and `>` [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) format codes in the [struct module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/struct.html#module-struct) to achieve the same result:

```
>>> struct.pack('<2h', *struct.unpack('>2h', original))
'\xde\xad\xc0\xde'
```

Happy [byte swapping](http://www.google.com/search?q=byte%20swapping%20in%20python) :-)

Comment: thank you for the explaining the difference for string reading in python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 20):

```
data = b'\xAD\xDE\xDE\xC0'
reversed_data = data[::-1]
print(reversed_data)
# b'\xc0\xde\xde\xad'
```

Comment: OP asks for reversing 2 by 2, not the whole bytes. e.g 0001abcd to 0100cdab

Answer (score 19):

In Python 3.4 you can use this:

```
>>> data = b'\xAD\xDE\xDE\xC0'
>>> swap_data = bytearray(data)
>>> swap_data.reverse()
```

the result is

```
bytearray(b'\xc0\xde\xde\xad')
```

Answer (score 2):

Python3

```py
bytes(reversed(b'\xAD\xDE\xDE\xC0'))
# b'\xc0\xde\xde\xad'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a list operator to reverse the values of a list --> nameOfList[::-1]

So, I might store the hex values as string and put them into a list then try something like:

```
def reverseList(aList):
rev = aList[::-1]
outString = ""
for el in rev:
    outString += el + " "
return outString
```