# how to re-order bytes in a python hex string and convert to long

Tags: python, python-2.7, byte

I have this long hex string 20D788028A4B59FB3C07050E2F30 In python 2.7 I want to extract the first 4 bytes, change their order, convert it to a signed number, divide it by 2^20 and then print it out.  In C this would be very easy for me :) but here I'm a little stuck.

For example the correct answer would extract the 4 byte number from the string above as 0x288D720.  Then divided by 2^20 would be 40.5525.  Mainly I'm having trouble figuring out the right way to do byte manipulation in python.  In C I would just grab pointers to each byte and shift them where I wanted them to go and cast into an int or a long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is great in strings, so let's use what we have:

```
s = "20D788028A4B59FB3C07050E2F30"
t = "".join([s[i-2:i] for i in range(8,0,-2)])
print int(t, 16) * 1.0 / pow(2,20)
```

But *dividing* by 2**20 comes a bit strange with bits, so maybe shifting is at least worth a mention too...

```
print int(t, 16) >> 20
```

After all, I would

```
print int(t, 16) * 1.0 / (1 << 20)
```

Comment: `int(str, int)` has a little known [second parameter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) indicating the base of the string to be converted

Comment: ohh ok I'd forgotten hex was base 16.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For an extraction you can just do
`foo[:8]`

Hex to bytes: [hexadecimal string to byte array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649407/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-python)

Rearrange bytes: [byte reverse AB CD to CD AB with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543065/byte-reverse-ab-cd-to-cd-ab-with-python)

You can use `struct` for conversion to long

And just do a normal division by `(2**20)`