# Try to reverse an bytearray(from hex) in python

Tags: python-3.x, hex, python-bytearray

I have the following script:

```py
hex_string = "c23dba5fcac1048b3c050266ceb6a0e870670021"
hex_bytes = bytearray.fromhex(hex_raw)
print(hex_bytes.reverse())
```

The problem it prints/returns `None`. I was wondering, because in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543065/byte-reverse-ab-cd-to-cd-ab-with-python/31856122#31856122) example it works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.reverse()` reverses in place and doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi thanks I think now I understand what to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue. The method `.reverse()` dont return anything, but changes the `bytearray`, so the code must be:

```
hex_string = "c23dba5fcac1048b3c050266ceb6a0e870670021"
hex_bytes = bytearray.fromhex(hex_raw)
hex_bytes.reverse()
print(hex_bytes)
```